# ListView.Refresh 'clears' the listview

Tags: c#, regex, file-io, directory, case-insensitive

My code is looping through operations and is adding feedback to a listview control. Previously, my code has been working OK, but something has changed today...

The listview control starts off like this:
[image: before]

...but after I issue a call to Update() or Refresh(), rather than show the items that I have added, it renders like this:

[image: after]

At this point, the control is still enabled and visible. In fact the only interaction my code has with it is to add new items and Update().

To add items, I'm using the following:

```
lvwDrawings.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[]
{
    drawing.PartNo,
    drawing.Revision.ToString(),
    drawing.Issue,
    drawing.DrgTypeText,
    errorStatus !=null ? errorStatus : drawing.Status,
    drawing.Filepath
}));
```

In case I'd introduced some problem here, I tested with the simpler `lvwDrawings.Items.Add("test");`, but the result was the same. If I do a QuickWatch, the control correctly tells me that it contains x items...

Comment: sounds like a transient glitch?  Try rebooting.  Try doing a full build.  Try disabling any other programs that may affect windows on your system.  Did you change any project properties?  Add any new references?  Does it happen if you create a new blank project and paste your code into it?

Comment: I tried restarting VS, but no change. I'll try a reboot now. Plenty of other changes have happened, but not concerning this control. I've been trying to think of changes that might be suspect...

Comment: have you tried to do a lvwDrawings.RedrawItems? Once you create the new ListViewItem, does the new item have any `null` properties?

Comment: @Dan-o - not a transient glitch - just a cock-up on my part. PEBCAK: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/PEBCAK

Answer (score 1):

OK, I've found the problem - for some unknown reason, where I'd previously had `lvwDrawings.Items.Clear()` to clear the list between different runs, I somehow ended up with `lvwDrawings.Clear()`. This clears not only the items in the listview, but also the columns.

It's curious on two counts: I would have though that when I tried to add a ListViewItem with specific columns that it would have objected when there weren't any columns, and also, what on earth did I think I was doing when I made the change(??!).

*Moderately interesting diversion:*

I discovered the problem by creating a second listview below the first, and working through until I hit the problem. As part of that process, I added columns in the design, one of which I called `Path`, to which the designer didn't object.

However, in the code, references to methods of the static class Path (e.g. `Path.GetDirectoryName()`) resulted in an error - 'ColumnHeader Path does not have a method 'xxx'' or similar. Clearly, it assumed that when I referred to Path, I was referring to the column within the listview.

Furthermore, when I went to rename the column (to 'FullPath'), it renamed all references to Path in the code, eg. `FullPath.GetDirectoryName()`....

Comment: Good job diagnosing and fixing your issue!  Nice to see people excersizing their debugging skills.

Comment: Oh, my debugging skills get more than enough practice. Sadly. ;)